# unresolved import for module imports in Visuial Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have opened a folder in VS code and I am trying to set it up. 
It's a python project and its directory structure is as:

```
Project
├── common_features
│   ├── ...
├── core
│   ├── features
│   └── main.py
│   └── tests
├── django project
│   ├── django_app1
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── ...
└── tests
│   ├── ...
└── runner.py
```

The project runs as a django project from the django_project dir. It uses modules located in common_features and core. Core is designed such that it could also run on its own. You can also run core from runner.py

The problem is that all our module imports are not being resolved but 3rd party packages work well.

```
unresolved import 'core.config' Python(unresolved-import)
```

In PyCharm, I have marked Project, core and django_project as "sources root" and it works like a charm. Not sure how to do that in VS code.

I have tried making some changes in launch.json and settings.json but none are working. I am new to VS code so I'm unable to understand what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding the following line to your settings.json file?

> {
>       "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./src"] 
>   }

More info about this here: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings